# OpenGL Vertex Buffer with non-constant size

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm creating [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). In my approach, I'm rendering many squares, which differs only in their position (size and color are the same). In [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing) they explain how to use method called *Instanced Rendering*, which can greatly increase render speed of each frame. In their example, they assume we know the size of vertex buffer, but it's not true in my case. Number of elements is changed every frame. That means creating new instance vertex buffer every frame.

Other possible option is to create one vertex buffer with size of largest possible number of offsets, but that would be memory inefficient.

What is the best option in my case?

Comment: Who says you have to draw **everything** at once? Why don't you draw the first half and then the next half?

Comment: Are you only drawing the 'alive' cells and not the 'dead' cells?
It's easier to suggest a method if you could describe what (visual) result you're aiming for.

Comment: If your portion of the screen to render is constant, you could draw all the cells on the screen passing a boolean to the shader telling to skip drawing dead cells.

Comment: Seriously, game of life screems like you want to use a texture insted. And actually, you can do the whole game logic via fragment shader + render-to-texture. And much more efficient than instancing squares.